# Why colesico is not choosen though performance is great

Tags: spring-boot

I'm explore few next generation framework to build a microservice web application.

On analysis come across the following

```
 1. colesico (https://github.com/colesico/java-frameworks-comparison)
 2. Micronaut (https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core)
 3. Quarkus (https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus)
 4. Spring Boot - (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot)

#1 - Not active 
#2 - 284 contributors - active
#3 - 884 contributors - active
#4 - 1039 contributors - active
```

Why colesico is not choosen though performance is great...as per the comparison defined in the github....

Out of the 4, which one is reliable and fast/performance wise good to go-ahead for next generation building of web application.

Thanks

Comment: We can't comment unless you tell us where this (so-called) "analysis" came from.  Who did it?  When?  How was it done?

Comment: Besides, the actual question here is *"which one is reliable and fast/performance wise good to go-ahead for next generation building of web application"*.  That is a request for a recommendation ... and that is off-topic for StackOverflow.